# changing background of RadioButton covered text on radiobutton android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-xml

I got some problem while changing RadioButton's background property

First of all i want to create Line below each Radio Button which are three in One Radiobutton Group

here is the below code

```
 <RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="@android:color/black"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioBtnFirst"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_radiogroup_divider"
        android:text="Answer 1"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioBtnTwo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_radiogroup_divider"
        android:text="Answer 2"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioBtnThree"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_radiogroup_divider"
        android:text="Answer 3"/>
</RadioGroup>
```

Now in drawable folder custom_radiogroup_divider.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

    <stroke
       android:width="0.3dp"
       android:color="@android:color/black" />

</shape>
```

but now problem is when i use background property

**the radio button will look like text is overlapping the radiobutton**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to set your radiobutton's background from Java code:

```
radioBtnFirst.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.custom_radiogroup_divider);
```

It works with checkbox too ;)

Answer (score 2):

Do not set drawable to background but set it to button.

Use this

```
  <RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioBtnFirst"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:button="@drawable/custom_radiogroup_divider"
    android:text="Answer 1" />
```

Comment: by doing button will remove radio icon on left side :(

Comment: @Raksha when you set Button attribute means you are customizing radiobutton..For that you have to make an image with particular background which you want to display and then set it.